# Не работает умножение в плагине Emmet

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

Работаю в текстовом редакторе VS Code, где уже установлен Emmet. Все абревиатуры работают, однако умножение элементов (например a*5) никак не хочет выполняться. Что делать?

Comment: Вообще из коробки должно работать. Посмотрите, может что не так в настройках...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте найти в настройках vscode
emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab
и поставить галку

Answer (score 1):

В настройках VS code найдите в поиске emmet, затем поставьте галочку под Trigger Expantion On Tab.